# Javascript/Thymeleaf table sort by date/time in format dd-MM-yyyy hh:MM:ss

Tags: javascript, date

I am working on a table that displays dates

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I am fairly new to javascript in general, I am struggling to modify the JS I am using in order to make this sort function work correctly. Currently it isn't comparing the dates properly. I have followed W3's example for this code, but I cannot figure out how to tweak it properly in order to get dates comparing properly.

The HTML:

It is worth noting I have made this table for my question, however in my live version the table is using ThymeLeaf and has dynamic dates rather than hardcoded dates.

```
<table id="myTable">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th onclick="sortTable(0)">Date</th>
    <th>Status</th>

</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>OLR</td>
    <td>12-11-2018 03:11:14</td>
    <td>SUBMITTED</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>AF</td>
    <td>12-11-2018 03:11:12</td>
    <td>SUBMITTED</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>SAF</td>
    <td>12-11-2018 02:11:27</td>
    <td>COLLECTION_COMPLETE</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>CTT</td>
    <td>15-11-2018 11:11:13</td>
    <td>UNSUBMITTED</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>WP</td>
    <td>19-11-2018 02:11:36</td>
    <td>SUBMITTED</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

The JS:

```
function sortTable(n) {
var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
table = document.getElementById("myTable");
switching = true;

dir = "asc";

while (switching) {
    switching = false;
    rows = table.rows;

    for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
        shouldSwitch = false;

        x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
        y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];

        if (dir == "asc") {
            if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
                shouldSwitch = true;
                break;
            }
        } else if (dir == "desc") {
            if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
                shouldSwitch = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
        rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
        switching = true;
        switchcount ++;
    } else {
        if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
            dir = "desc";
            switching = true;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I have been working on this for about 8 hours so far today and I am really struggling. I have attempted to convert the elements to dates first before comparing but haven't been able to get it working.

Any help is appreciated.

After some help below progress has been made, however when I click the header to sort my table, a lot of the content disappears.

My new sort table function:

```
function sortTable() {

const dates = [...document
    .getElementById('myTable')
    .querySelectorAll('td')
]
    .filter(x => x.textContent.match(/\d{2}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}/))
    .map(x => {
        const [d, t] = x.textContent.trim().split(' ');
        const [day, month, yr] = d.split('-').map(Number);
        const [hr, min, sec] = t.split(':').map(Number);
        return new Date(yr, month - 1, day, hr, min, sec);
    });


const sorted = dates.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a > b) return 1;
    if (b > a) return -1;
    return 0;
});


const html = '<tr><id="timestamp">Last Updated</td></tr>' + sorted
    .map(date => {
        const yr = date.getFullYear();
        const month = date.getMonth() + 1;
        const day = date.getDate();
        const hr = date.getHours();
        const min = date.getMinutes();
        const sec = date.getSeconds();

        const dateString = `${day}-${month}-${yr} ${hr}:${min}:${sec}`;
        return `<tr><td>${dateString}</td></tr>`;
    })
    .join('');

document.getElementById('myTable').innerHTML = html;
```

}

Comment: 1st, include sample input in a form we can copy/paste, not an image.

Comment: Hello, I have edited my original post. I am using dynamic data so have put together a table for this example.

Comment: DOM mutations (caused by trying to remove and reinsert nodes as you go) are slow, slow, slow. Sort in JS and re-generate the table (see my answer). Also let's you use the built in sort algorithm, no need to roll your own (tricky, as you've discovered).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's plug-in for jQuery called [DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/) which does that and whole lot of other things. Why would you invent your own bicycle?

To get very basic set of features (which includes sorting) you just need to do what DataTables front page suggests: point to jQuery, DataTables and its stylesheet in your header.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

Or, you may use local copies of those.

Then, you simply call

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#myTable').DataTable();
} );
```

And let DataTables take care of the rest
http://jsfiddle.net/1fvkp6L0/14/

Comment: I have tried to use them but only getting issues because of my lack of understanding, I am completely open to a solution that uses DateTables

Comment: This does not answer the question. While one could conceivably use datatables (or vaadin or anything else in the same vein) to solve this, you need to actually post how to do it.

Comment: No problem, I'll submit fiddle first thing tomorrow. As i do so, I'm sure you change that minus for plus, despite of how much effort you put into the code below.

Comment: @ygorbunkov Are you referring to me? I haven't voted :x I appreciate any help put forward, despite what I have posted I have put a lot of effort into this code and have been working on it pretty solidly for a few days. What I have posted is the best variant of what I currently have. I say best because when I click, something was actually happening. I have explored DateTables, along with Sorttables(which I had good progress with, but I feel was way too ahead of me to be able to tweak the functions in a way I needed for date comparing) and tablesorter but I am struggling.

Comment: I downvoted, which I will gladly retract if ygorbunkov posts working code that solves your problem.

Comment: 2 Jared Smith: `var ygorbunkovPromise = new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(question => {
 if(provideSolution(question)) resolve(dataTablesSoluion);
  }, 13*60*60*1000);
});
ygorbunkovPromise.then(solution => {
  if(isBetter(solution)) upVote();
});`

Comment: Brilliant, thank you very much. I also now completely understand my issue with DataTables before, I didn't have <thead> tags which are required, when I swapped to my mock table (which has them tags) it became apparent. I will add to your JS fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/1fvkp6L0/14/ because, it doesn't be default sort the date/time correctly, I added another bit of sample data to display this (datetime : 19-10-2018 12:10:32) and then added moments to the javascript displayed in the fiddle.

Comment: Enjoy and don't forget to mark your question 'solved'

Comment: I have done this :) - maybe it would be beneficial for future viewers if you post my fiddle in your answer as well, since by default your solution doesn't work with every date format.

Comment: @ygorbunkov even if I weren't inclined to change my vote thanks to your solution, that comment is pure gold :) have an upvote

Answer (score 0):

First is getting the list of dates in a form we can *actually sort*, i.e. an array:

```
const dates = [...document
  .getElementById('id-of-the-table')
  .querySelectorAll('td')
]
.filter(x => x.textContent.match(/\d{2}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}/))
.map(x => {
  const [d, t] = x.textContent.trim().split(' ');
  const [day, month, yr] = d.split('-').map(Number);
  const [hr, min, sec] = t.split(':').map(Number);
  return new Date(yr, month - 1, day, hr, min, sec);
});
```

Now we can sort them based on the date value:

```
const sorted = dates.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a > b) return 1;
  if (b > a) return -1;
  return 0;
});
```

To switch descending/ascending, just reverse the conditional. Then use the sorted values to re-generate the table:

```
const html = sorted
.map(date => {
  const yr = date.getFullYear();
  const month = date.getMonth() + 1;
  // etc. etc.
  const datestring = `${day}-${month}-${yr} ${hr}:${min}:${sec}`;
  return `<tr><td>${datestring}</td></tr>`;
})
.join('');

document.getElementById('id-for-table').innerHTML = html;
```

Comment: Hello, this is great and has helped me progress for the first time in 2 days, to see my table actually sorting is very nice, however because 
return `<tr><td>${dateString}</td></tr>` the rest of my table is deleted when I click the header, showing just the rows with the dates in and nothing else. Do I need to now return the whole table again?

Comment: @ChrisPeters no, just add a header row to the output `const  html = '<tr><td>Last Updated</td></tr>' + sorted.map...`

Comment: Hey thanks again, I have tried to add it but it doesn't stop the rest of my table disappearing, also it removes the CSS for some of it.

Only the header for "Last Updated" stays after your addition, the rest still disappear but Last Updated also loses it's CSS.

Would you be able to provide an example using my table above including the code that keeps the elements on sort. I will add another comment to show you what is happening in just a second.

Comment: I have edited my original post to demonstrate the new issue - I couldn't post pictures etc in a comment.

Comment: @ChrisPeters you just have to change the output to contain what you want including adding the css classes to the relevant elements. I mean, how do you generate that table in the first place? Just feed the new data back into the same logic.

Comment: It is generated using Java+HTML+Thymeleaf, I am not sure how to feed it back into the table, all the data is originally generated using Java. The data will be refreshed every 10seconds or so so I don't want to re-run the Java every 10 seconds for sorting purposes. I am a complete novice with JS so I really wouldn't know where to start from what you're saying. Maybe a different solution will be better suited for me?

Comment: @ChrisPeters you mean you're reloading the entire page every 10 seconds? How does the 'data get refreshed'?

Comment: Sorry what I meant was, if I used java to sort it would involve rerunning the java everytime the page was refreshed to sort the data again which is why I have opted to do the sorting with JS instead, so the data comes from java and because of that I don't know how to return the JavaScript data correctly back into my table

Comment: @ChrisPeters I don't understand. You say the data is being refreshed every 10 seconds. **How?** because if it's coming from Java in some language-neutral data format (JSON, XML) then by definition you've got some JavaScript code *somewhere* in your app that uses it to update the DOM. If you're getting it from Java as HTML then either you're refreshing the page every 10 seconds, or again, by definition you have some JavaScript code that updates the DOM.

Comment: Sorry, I am not explaining myself right. What I mean is the HTML page refreshes every 10 seconds. I am using Java with Spring MVC to collect the data from a cassandra table and using ThymeLeaf HTML to display that data, if my table updates, when my HTML page refreshes the data is then displayed.

What I mean is I don't want to make the sort function in Java because anytime someone clicks the column they want sorting it will re-run the Java again to produce a fresh list which isn't efficient, the only JavaScript I have consciously running is what you've talked me through so far.

Comment: Isn't efficient to hit the server again? When you're already hitting it every 10 seconds? When you're doing server side rendering for an application that updates it's view every 10 seconds? That's the least of your worries. If you really want efficiency re write as an SPA that uses AJAX to poll a REST endpoint for JSON data and use client-side templating. Otherwise just hit the server again when the user clicks and write your sort function in Java. You wouldn't be the first, and you won't be the last.

Comment: You do make a good point, I could also add that 10 seconds hasn't really been set, it could end up being much longer but it is what I have been using for testing. However I think what you're saying is right, it would have been easier for me in the beginning to write the sort function in Java, that being said I also would like to learn what I am currently struggling to do in JS because I know I should learn more JS for my career goals.

Comment: @ChrisPeters ok. Generally speaking it's way easier to manipulate data in data structures and then convert it to something to be rendered. The best solution for now is to write the sort in Java, but if the refresh interval is going to be tight I'd lobby the bosses to do it as an SPA instead.

Comment: Jared, I have a working solution above now which more directly answers the question above, however I wanted to thank you separately for explaining so much, I have learned a lot from our discussion and very much appreciate it.